Is Maximum Entropy the solution I am looking for (is the characterization of Entropy optimum for my situation)?
My end goal is a posterior predictive (or at least an entire parametric distribution of possible unobserved values conditional on the observed values). As much as I hate making assumptions I hate discarding/filtering/wasting data for "robustness". If I could have a nonparametric approach that gives me as a result an entire parametric (with the desired parametres μ and σ) distribution of possible unobserved values conditional on the observed values without wasting a single piece of information I would be jubilant and overjoyed.
I am not a huge fan of making assumptions but I hate winsorizing etc much more.
Should I just use $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,\Omega) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ for the likelihood with Discrete Uniform Distributions (as flat uninformative priors) on the same support and compute a "classical" Bayesian Posterior Predictive, could doing away with the (sub)additivity in the characterisation of entropy (the information learned from events is equal or less than the sum of the information learned from each event) still lead to a single definition of entropy and a maximum entropy distribution for given mean, variance and support with fatter tails?
$$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,\Omega) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$
Seems to be the Maximum Entropy Distribution for given mean, variance and support. But I'd rather have a distribution with fatter tails (for the same mean, variance, support) for my likelihood.
For example I am calculating the Posterior Predictive from a class that sat a test with 25 multiple choice questions (with some absentees) and I want to get an idea on how would the absentees score on the same test (I also want to get information on whether the test was easy or hard, on whether the teacher did a good job, whether the class is smart or challenged, whether the grading was sloppy, lenient, strict, impartial).
The Support (Ω) is 0, 1, 2..... 25. Ι am most certain that the scores of the students are positively correlated. They knew a test was coming up so the confident ones sat it, they all had the same teacher so if the teacher was good (a good indicator would be a good score on the Test) all the scores would improve. For all shorts of reasons I belueve they are possitevely correlated (If I know one did great I am confident the others did better that I would otherwise believe) but I can't quantify this belief (I have no clue on whether this relationship is linear, exponential, quadratic, cubic etc).
I want to be able to use the same method with different supports (Different Test Score Ranges or different purposes).
